# Error: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php, pdo

I wrote a function like this:

```
function tim_kiem($tenchu,$sohieutoba,$sothututhu,$gia_dat){
        global $dbh;
        $where="1=1";
        $tenchu = "%".$tenchu."%";

        if($tenchu<>""){

        $where=$where." and tenchu like :tenchu";
        }
        if($sohieutoba<>0){
        $where=$where." and (sohieutoba=:sohieutoba)";
        }
        if($sothututhu<>0){
        $where=$where." and (sothututhu=:sothututhu)";
        }
        if($gia_dat<>""){
        $where=$where." and gia_dat=:gia_dat";
        }
        $sql="SELECT * FROM mybinh WHERE ".$where;


        $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindValue(':tenchu', $tenchu);
        $sth->bindValue(':sohieutoba', $sohieutoba);
        $sth->bindValue(':sothututhu', $sothututhu);
        $sth->bindValue(':gia_dat', $gia_dat);

        $sth->execute();

        $row=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row;

    }
```

The result is ok but it attatch a warning

> "PDOStatement::bindValue(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:
>   :sohieutoba..."

, if I input to both of `$sohieutoba` and `$sothututhu`, the result without any warning, I don't know where I'm wrong. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you use conditions to create your query, you should also bind values depending on your conditions. Now you may use only one condition `if($tenchu<>"")` but bind all 4 paramters what is wrong.

The easiest solution is to simple repeat your statements:

```
function tim_kiem($tenchu,$sohieutoba,$sothututhu,$gia_dat){
        global $dbh;
        $where="1=1";
        $tenchu = "%".$tenchu."%";

        if($tenchu<>""){

        $where=$where." and tenchu like :tenchu";
        }
        if($sohieutoba<>0){
        $where=$where." and (sohieutoba=:sohieutoba)";
        }
        if($sothututhu<>0){
        $where=$where." and (sothututhu=:sothututhu)";
        }
        if($gia_dat<>""){
        $where=$where." and gia_dat=:gia_dat";
        }
        $sql="SELECT * FROM mybinh WHERE ".$where;

        $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
        if($tenchu<>""){        
           $sth->bindValue(':tenchu', $tenchu);
        }
        if($sohieutoba<>0){
          $sth->bindValue(':sohieutoba', $sohieutoba);
        }
        if($sothututhu<>0){
           $sth->bindValue(':sothututhu', $sothututhu); 
        }
        if($gia_dat<>""){
           $sth->bindValue(':gia_dat', $gia_dat);
        }

        $sth->execute();

        $row=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row;

    }
```

However it's not the most elegant way. You could for example use only one condition and create array and later in loop bind your paramters

Comment: I'm new to php, so using loop is bad, could you show me how to use the loop? I have tried using the loop but it's not work.